# Unable to connect bluetooth devices after upgrade to 23.04

Tags: upgrade, xubuntu, bluetooth

As I always do, I upgraded my xubuntu version to 23.04. The thing is that now I'm unable to connect my devices to the bluetooth. There's an error message that reads "Connection Failed: br-connection-profile-unavailable".

The devices get paired but do not connect to bluetooth...

PS: In the past, I had a problem with the bluetooth connection as well, after upgrading to the previous version. But in that case, the bluetooth manager wouldn't open and it was apparently "hard-blocked" but I fixed it with `echo "blacklist sony-laptop" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/sony-laptop.conf then reboot.`

Comment: Did you find a solution to this yet?

Comment: Yes, I did. I don't remember how, though.

Comment: I finally did too and the way I did it was launching `bluetoothctl connect` right after `bluetoothctl pair` succeeded. If I let the pairing success linger a little too long then the connection fails.